# How to explicitly wait for the text in an element to be changed in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating an web portal. I came across one different problem. I have two dropdown lists say A and B. When the page loads, A will have first value from list, accordingly B has it's value. When user selects value from A, correspondingly value in B changes. So, I stuck at how could I add explicit wait for this. I tried the following code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementPath));
```

but the values in dropdownlist B are already present in the page load. So, it is not waiting for the text in B changes, it is taking the default value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`presenceOfElementLocated` is checking if the elements exists in the DOM. It doesn't mean that they are visible and you can interact with them.

Try

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elementPath));
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(elementPath, text));
```

You can wait until the element is visible or with text. For more [Expected Conditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

Comment: but when the page loads it's already visible I think... I will try that... by the way is visibilityOfElementLocated and presenceOfElementLocated Different?

Comment: I think textinElementPresent will work...

Comment: Thing is I don't know what that text come...

Comment: @LokeshS I added the answer to your question to my answer.

Comment: but the problem here is i don't know what is that text to use in textToBePresentInElementLocated

Comment: @LokeshS you said that when you change A the value in B changes accordingly. You can build `Map<String, String>` with A values as keys and matching B values as map values.